# Let $V$ be the vector space of real polynomials of degree at most $2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Let $V$ be the vector space of real polynomials of degree at most $2$. Define a linear operator $T \colon V \to V$ by $$T(x^i)=\sum_{j=0}^{i}x^j,\,\,i=0,1,2.$$
>
> Now what is the matrix of $T^{-1}$ with respect to the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$?

Comment: Check your matrix for $T$ again. It doesn't seem to be satisfying $T(x) = 1+x$.

Comment: @MilindHegde Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2):

Check your matrix for $T$ again. It doesn't seem to be satisfying $T(x)=1+x$.

Answer (score 1):

We have, $T(x^i)=1+x+...+x^i$ and so $T(1)=1,T(x)=1+x,T(x^2)=1+x+x^2.$ Now the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is given by $\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &1 \\ 
 0&1  &1 \\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}$ and so $T^{-1}$ is given by: \begin{pmatrix}
1 &-1  &0 \\ 
 0&1  &-1 \\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix} .